# Find Google AdWords Account or originated campaign

Tags: google-ads-api, sem

Is it possible to know the original account owner based on [this](https://www.somewebsite.com.au/?cmpid=sem:goo:162261461469&s_kwcid=somewebsite%20pharmacy&kwmt=e&gclid=Cj0KCQiAi7XQBRDnARIsANeLIeuVxUT9caAC_TriZCbn0JsiHYImQMp-e7lMPr6ovWpwvw9uv4T7uEEaAkKKEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) Google Maps ad?

Thanks for any leads.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, link seems to be broken, but AFAIK, it's not possible to track ANY AdWords account owner, not even the email since only lead you might have is [GCLID](https://www.wordstream.com/gclid), which represents campaign identification for Google and the page owner.

The only one who might help you is Google support itself but doesn't seem likely if no law is broken.